# Why checker deselect doesn't work on object created by array

Tags: modifiers, selection-tools

In Blender 3.2 - I have created 10 cubes using an array modifier having a relative offset the same as the side of the cube. After I apply the array modifier; when I select its faces, I don't see any overlapping vertices, but the checker deselect doesn't work, it only deselected the active cell. The object seems to work as an array of separate objects rather than 1 object. Do you know how to fix it?

[image]

I have tried to separate by loose parts and join again, but it did not help.

When I do the same using an object created through repeating face extrude, the checker deselect works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure.. was 'Merge' checked in the _Array_ modifier?

Comment: @moonboots Vaasha seems to be having this problem after applying the modifier, the way I read this... I can't reproduce ,,,

Comment: oops ok........... yes yu must be right about the merge option

Answer (score 2):

Checker deselect only work on contiguous selection.

Make sure all the faces are connected by using the `Merge` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) -> `By Distance` tool

Then the checker deselect should work.

You can avoid this step in the future by enabling 'merge' on the array modifier like the comments pointed out